# Can different energies be merged to "create" new kinds of energy, with respect to mass and energy conservations?

Tags: energy

If energy and mass are the same thing, and matter which has mass -- chemicals to be exact -- 
can be combined to make new chemical compounds, can the same be done to energy? If so, how would it be done?

Comment: A particle accelerator is a machine that takes electrical energy from a power plant, which it converts into matter. CERN is creating plenty of antiprotons, right now, and they are even producing anti-hydrogen, not to mention lots of unstable "stuff" like the Higgs particles that the LHC was built for to find.

Comment: "Fascinating, captain:  a new form of pure energy"

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is done with heat differential engines all the time. Heat is applied to one side of a piston and it is cooled on the other side, gas within a piston expands and collapses, the heat energy is converted into mechanical energy. Another example is when a photon traveling with kinetic energy is absorbed by an electron in an atom and the electron becomes a free electron thus producing electrical energy.